# Nginx Chunked Encoding Response Randomly Truncated

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, truncate, chunked-encoding, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an upstream server that simply starts a chunked encoding response and sends a small chunk every second for 100 chunks.

When I hit the upstream server directly like so, all works fine.

```
curl --raw 10.244.7.248:4000/test/stream
```

However, when I go through nginx like so, the response gets cut off at random times.

```
curl --raw localhost/test/stream
```

Curl returns

```
curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

and the nginx logs only show

```
::1 - [::1] - - [24/Oct/2017:11:09:02 +0000] "GET /test/stream HTTP/1.1" 200 440 "-" "curl/7.47.0" 95 44.783 [bar-bar-80] 10.244.7.248:4000 440 44.783 200
```

Notice in this example, the response appears to complete successfully with a 200 but only after 44.783 seconds when it should have been roughly 100 seconds. Every time I try this I get a cut off at a different number of seconds.

I am running Kubernetes Nginx Ingress Controller 0.9.0-beta.14 with `gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.9.0-beta.14`

The nginx.conf is very long, but here are some snippets

```
daemon off;

worker_processes 2;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

worker_rlimit_nofile 498976;
worker_shutdown_timeout 10s ;

events {
    multi_accept        on;
    worker_connections  16384;
    use                 epoll;
}

http {
    real_ip_header      X-Forwarded-For;

    real_ip_recursive   on;
    set_real_ip_from    0.0.0.0/0;

    geoip_country       /etc/nginx/GeoIP.dat;
    geoip_city          /etc/nginx/GeoLiteCity.dat;
    geoip_proxy_recursive on;
    sendfile            on;

    aio                 threads;
    aio_write           on;

    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;

    log_subrequest      on;

    reset_timedout_connection on;

    keepalive_timeout  75s;
    keepalive_requests 100;

    client_header_buffer_size       1k;
    client_header_timeout           60s;
    large_client_header_buffers     4 8k;
    client_body_buffer_size         8k;
    client_body_timeout             60s;

    http2_max_field_size            4k;
    http2_max_header_size           16k;

    types_hash_max_size             2048;
    server_names_hash_max_size      8192;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size   128;
    map_hash_bucket_size            64;

    proxy_headers_hash_max_size     512;
    proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size  64;

    variables_hash_bucket_size      64;
    variables_hash_max_size         2048;

    underscores_in_headers          off;
    ignore_invalid_headers          on;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type text/html;
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_types application/atom+xml application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/rss+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf application/x-web-app-manifest
+json application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon text/css text/plain text/x-component;
    gzip_proxied any;

    # Custom headers for response

    server_tokens on;

    # disable warnings
    uninitialized_variable_warn off;

    # Additional available variables:
    # $namespace
    # $ingress_name
    # $service_name
    log_format upstreaminfo '$the_real_ip - [$the_real_ip] - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" $request_length $request_time [$proxy_upstrea
m_name] $upstream_addr $upstream_response_length $upstream_response_time $upstream_status';

    map $request_uri $loggable {
        default 1;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log upstreaminfo if=$loggable;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;

    resolver 10.0.0.10 valid=30s;

    # Retain the default nginx handling of requests without a "Connection" header
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default          upgrade;
        ''               close;
    }

    # Trust HTTP X-Forwarded-* Headers, but use direct values if they're missing.
    map $http_x_forwarded_for $the_real_ip {
        # Get IP address from X-Forwarded-For HTTP header
        default          $realip_remote_addr;
        ''               $remote_addr;
    }

    # trust http_x_forwarded_proto headers correctly indicate ssl offloading
    map $http_x_forwarded_proto $pass_access_scheme {
        default          $http_x_forwarded_proto;
        ''               $scheme;
    }

    map $http_x_forwarded_port $pass_server_port {
        default           $http_x_forwarded_port;
        ''                $server_port;
    }
    map $http_x_forwarded_host $best_http_host {
        default          $http_x_forwarded_host;
        ''               $this_host;
    }
    map $pass_server_port $pass_port {
        443              443;
        default          $pass_server_port;
    }

    # Map a response error watching the header Content-Type
    map $http_accept $httpAccept {
        default          html;
        application/json json;
        application/xml  xml;
        text/plain       text;
    }

    map $httpAccept $httpReturnType {
        default          text/html;
        json             application/json;
        xml              application/xml;
        text             text/plain;
    }

    # Obtain best http host
    map $http_host $this_host {
        default          $http_host;
        ''               $host;
    }

    server_name_in_redirect off;
    port_in_redirect        off;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    # turn on session caching to drastically improve performance
    ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;

    # allow configuring ssl session tickets
    ssl_session_tickets on;

    # slightly reduce the time-to-first-byte
    ssl_buffer_size 4k;

    # allow configuring custom ssl ciphers
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-R
SA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:D
HE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-C
BC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_ecdh_curve auto;

    proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
    upstream bar-bar-80 {
        # Load balance algorithm; empty for round robin, which is the default
        least_conn;

        keepalive 32;

        server 10.244.7.248:4000 max_fails=0 fail_timeout=0;
    }
    server {
        server_name bar.gigalixir.com;
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        set $proxy_upstream_name "-";

        listen 443  ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443  ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate                         /ingress-controller/ssl/bar-bar-tls.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key                     /ingress-controller/ssl/bar-bar-tls.pem;

        more_set_headers                        "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains;";
        location / {
            set $proxy_upstream_name "bar-bar-80";

            set $namespace      "bar";
            set $ingress_name   "bar";
            set $service_name   "bar";

            # enforce ssl on server side
            if ($pass_access_scheme = http) {
                return 301 https://$best_http_host$request_uri;
            }
            port_in_redirect off;

            client_max_body_size                    "0";

            proxy_set_header Host                   $best_http_host;
            # Pass the extracted client certificate to the backend

            # Allow websocket connections
            proxy_set_header                        Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header                        Connection        $connection_upgrade;

            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP              $the_real_ip;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $the_real_ip;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host       $best_http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port       $pass_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto      $pass_access_scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Original-URI         $request_uri;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme               $pass_access_scheme;

            proxy_set_header X-Auth-Request-Redirect $request_uri;
            # mitigate HTTPoxy Vulnerability
            # https://www.nginx.com/blog/mitigating-the-httpoxy-vulnerability-with-nginx/
            proxy_set_header Proxy                  "";

            # Custom headers to proxied server

            proxy_connect_timeout                   5s;
            proxy_send_timeout                      60s;
            proxy_read_timeout                      60s;

            proxy_redirect                          off;
            proxy_buffering                         off;
            proxy_buffer_size                       "4k";
            proxy_buffers                           4 "4k";
            proxy_request_buffering                 "on";

            proxy_http_version                      1.1;

            proxy_cookie_domain                     off;
            proxy_cookie_path                       off;

            # In case of errors try the next upstream server before returning an error
            proxy_next_upstream                     error timeout invalid_header http_502 http_503 http_504;

            proxy_pass http://bar-bar-80;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I determined that the connection is closed when the nginx configuration is reloaded, which happens periodically with the Kubernetes Nginx Ingress Controller. The nginx workers drain connections for 10 seconds which is not enough in this case. I filed an issue here
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/54505

From the github issue above

> you can adjust the drain of connections in the workers adjusting the
>   value of the setting `worker-shutdown-timeout: XXXs` in the
>   configuration configmap. The default value is 10 seconds.